Shortcut to take photo with webcam while its open in other software
I bought a veeeery expensive razer webcam (Razer Kiyo Pro Ultra) purely to take only photos easily directly with my computer and the software (Razer Synapse) to control everything seems great, but one issue, it doesnt have the option to take a photo or even video in its software..,
Closing the software and opening the windows camera wipes all my settings and i kinda like having having access to all the settings and preview window razer synapse has.
My question/thought is, since the webcam is currently being activated and is on and previewing an image, is there any way to send the trigger to take a photo via some kinda shortcut,prompt,batch file,powershell i dunno?

There are many third-party webcam apps (e.g., https://www.cyberlink.com/blog/streaming-software/1104/best-free-webcam-software), and there are many tools to convert a keypress to an action, such as taking a picture with a webcam (e.g., https://www.autohotkey.com/). What have you tried?

@DrMoishePippik I'm trying to avoid having a seperate app because it wont have the same settings the razer webcam software does, But the software itself doesnt have the option to take photos, just to preview the image. You might be right on autohotkey though, im seeing threads with people trying to do something similar

Is Razer Synapse SUPPOSED to be able to record video and take pictures, or is it only a "streaming" recording software? If Razer Synapse doesn't have options to take pictures or record the video you want, then you're out of luck: what you want isn't possible. Sorry. You could suggest an update to the software features to Razer, but otherwise you MUST use a different tool.

@music2myear Yeah it doesnt have the option to record video or take pictures, i got caught offguard because every single other default webcam software i've ever seen has the option, but yeah you're right i think its literally on razer at this point to add the feature. I thought i was getting close by using ffmpeg commands in a .bat file and it works, but if the preview window is open in synapse the command doesnt work, i'd be flying blind taking photos
